# SonarQube6.7.1 java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Now when I use SonarQube 6.7.1, the following exception occurs, but before everything is perfect
SonarQube Scanne:3.0.3.778
SonarQube:6.7.1
MySQL:5.7

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: load called twice for thread 'Worker 0 (UUID=AWEm-qWI05DFyrKNBSuu) on ce-worker-0' or state wasn't cleared last time it was used
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
    at org.sonar.server.setting.ThreadLocalSettings.load(ThreadLocalSettings.java:153)
    at org.sonar.ce.settings.SettingsLoader.start(SettingsLoader.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor460.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:134)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.container.TaskContainerImpl.bootup(TaskContainerImpl.java:77)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:71)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:134)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.findAndProcessTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:97)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.withCustomizedThreadName(CeWorkerImpl.java:81)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:73)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the circumstances under which you see this error, and where (which log) you see this error.

Comment: I also got it, this is coming when analysis is happening in sonarqube web. The last analysis has failed. More details available on the Background Tasks page.